# Erro: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, ascii

Incompatible character encodings: **UTF-8** and **ASCII-8BIT**.

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
"authenticity_token"=>"3cl0R8ghLDvPMGkh0I+LCrzQjmyu1donLE9y58rIT1k=",
"post"=>{"title"=>"Somos apaixonados por mÃºsica!",
"caption"=>"Estamos entrando na fase final da construÃ§Ã£o do estÃºdio. Mau podemos esperar para iniciar os trabalhos dos grandes artistas que nos esperam.",
"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000103339718 @original_filename="Captura de Tela 2014-05-30 a\xCC\x80s 11.45.37 (2).png",
@content_type="image/png",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[photo]\"; filename=\"Captura de Tela 2014-05-30 a\xCC\x80s 11.45.37 (2).png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/qa/qas8gqrFHKeYuO3C3gst+E+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20140604-1488-amcll7>>,
"style_photo"=>"1"},
"commit"=>"Cadastrar NotÃ­cia"}
```

**PROBLEMA:**

O problema esta no nome do arquivo que estou tentando subir, nele contém um acento(*Captura de Tela 2014-05-30 às 11.45.37 (2).png*) e dai está gerando esse erro.

Existe alguma forma de resolver isso?

Comment: Você poderia incluir o seu arquivo config/enviroment.rb? E verifique se o seu application.rb contém: config.encoding = "utf-8"

Comment: Ja setei os dois com utf8

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```ruby
file_data = params[:import_file].tempfile.read.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
utf8_file_data = file_data.encode(utf8_format)
```

Retirado [desta pergunta do Stack-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893926/rails-parse-upload-file-xde-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8)