# Importação .txt para MySQL - valores entre strings

Tags: php, string, importação

Tenho um arquivo TXT que contém diversos registros diferentes, em alguns casos preciso pegar as informações que estão entre 2 strings, ex: `Cliente: FULANO DE TAL CPF:` preciso do que esta entre `Cliente: e CPF:`.

Em outras partes do mesmo documento preciso pegar os primeiros 12 caracteres de uma linha após a string `Tipo_OS:` caso exista alguma informação após o `Tipo_OS:` e antes de outra string também fixa no documento, pois pode ou não existir dados entre essas strings.
Obs. não tenho um caracter separador padrão para gerar minhas arrays, poderia utilizar o `:`, porém alguns dados não estão após o `:` e sim na linha abaixo ou ainda após outros dados da linha abaixo.

Sei que parece meio confuso, porém o que já consegui foi o seguinte:
encontrei uma função na internet que me permite pegar valores entre 2 strings.

```
function GetBetween($var1="",$var2="",$pool){

    $temp1 = strpos($pool,$var1)+strlen($var1);
    $result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));  
    $dd=strpos($result,$var2);        
    if($dd == 0){ 
        $dd = strlen($result);    
    }    
    return substr($result,0,$dd);  
}
```

Até é funcional, porém no `echo` continua aparecendo os outros dados do documento excluindo a exibição somente a string que defini como inicial e final.

Inicialmente o que preciso seria o seguinte, encontrar um valor entre 2 strings e exibir somente ele, porém quero definir varios valores entre 2 strings até capturar todas informações dessa Ordem de serviço, após eu capturar tudo eu necessite rodar um `while` para verificar se existem mais coisas nas próximas páginas, montando assim meu banco de dados com as ordens de serviços contidas nesse documento. Toda vez que o documento ler `Cliente:` ele identificar que é o começo de um novo registro.

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do ficheiro `.txt`?

Comment: Nesse modelo abaixo, são 3 Ordem de Serviço.

Comment: Excedeu o tamanho, vou colocar somente 2 registros

Comment: vou upar o arquivo... não posso colar o arquivo todo.. excede o tamanho

Comment: Segue link do arquivo .txt no mediafire

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?1pvi6p2ag92sx7o

Comment: Conseguiu Visualizar Sergio?

Comment: Sabe porque criaram o xml e o json ?

Comment: Então Edilson, essa pergunta ficou meio sem nexo... Se tem alguma coisa a acrescentar para poder ajudar um brother com problemas fico agradecido!!!
Esse tipo de comentário não ajuda em nada...
Tem alguma coisa que posso fazer com Json ou XML que vai me ajudar na minha conversão do TXT para MYSQL???
Obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto vai dar-lhe algum trabalho e idealmente devia estar já numa base de dados.

Aqui fica uma ajuda usando RegEx. Expressões regulares podem ser muito úteis neste tipo de situação. Dê uma olhada a esta [**regex que fiz para o seu caso**](http://regex101.com/r/oG6cM7).

[Um exemplo online **aqui**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fdb2011b3dbb8ef669487241e500844745a37ef2) (clique em 'execute code')

No fundo vai procurar todas as ocorrências e gerar um array com o que encontrar. Você só tem de defenir os campos.

Alguns parametros relevantes da regex:

`()` - imdica uma captura, qua vai ser colhida pelo php
`.*` - qualquer coisa menos quebra de linhas
`\s` - quebra de linha
`\s{1,}` - uma ou mais quebras de linha

Assim esta regex,

```
$regex = '/Cliente:(.*)CPF\/C\.N\.P\.J\.:(.*)\sEndereço:(.*)CEP:(.*)\s{1,}Tel EBT:\s{1,}Tel Res:(.*)Tel Outros:(.*)Tel Comercial:(.*)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $txt, $dados);
var_dump($dados);
```

com a função [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) do php deu-me isto:

```
{
[0] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(210) "Cliente: FULANO DE TAL CPF/C.N.P.J.: 123456789123 Endereço: R RITA ALVES PEREIRA , 01 -CARAPICUIBA -CARAPICUIBA-SP CEP: 6365000 Tel EBT: Tel Res: 01141874187 Tel Outros: Tel Comercial: 011999999999 "[1] => string(205) "Cliente: OUTRO FULANO DE TAL CPF/C.N.P.J.: 00000000011 Endereço: R ANTONIO FL, 01 -VILA DIRCE -CARAPICUIBA-SP CEP: 6343000 Tel EBT: Tel Res: 01141464146 Tel Outros: Tel Comercial: 011999999999 "[2] => string(192) "Cliente: MAIS UM FULANO DE TAL CPF/C.N.P.J.: 00000000011 Endereço: R TIBIRICA, 00 -VILA DIRCE -CARAPICUIBA-SP CEP: 6335000 Tel EBT: Tel Res: 01141674167 Tel Outros: Tel Comercial: "
    }

[1] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(15) " FULANO DE TAL "[1] => string(21) " OUTRO FULANO DE TAL "[2] => string(23) " MAIS UM FULANO DE TAL "
    }

[2] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(15) " 123456789123 "[1] => string(14) " 00000000011 "[2] => string(14) " 00000000011 "
    }

[3] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(56) " R RITA ALVES PEREIRA , 01 -CARAPICUIBA -CARAPICUIBA-SP "[1] => string(46) " R ANTONIO FL, 01 -VILA DIRCE -CARAPICUIBA-SP "[2] => string(44) " R TIBIRICA, 00 -VILA DIRCE -CARAPICUIBA-SP "
    }

[4] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(10) " 6365000 "[1] => string(10) " 6343000 "[2] => string(10) " 6335000 "
    }

[5] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(13) " 01141874187 "[1] => string(13) " 01141464146 "[2] => string(13) " 01141674167 "
    }

[6] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(1) " "[1] => string(1) " "[2] => string(1) " "
    }

[7] => array(
    3
)
    {
    [0] => string(15) " 011999999999 "[1] => string(15) " 011999999999 "[2] => string(2) " "
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou fazer alguns testes, em relação a ja devia estar em uma base de dados, na verdade está, porem a unica forma de extrair e importar tais dados do atual banco de dados é por meio de um arquvo pdf, pdf esse que extrai o .txt em questão.

Comment: @Ðracø que base de dados usa?

Comment: Não tenho nem idéia, é um sistema da Claro, só temos acesso a exportação de um PDF.

Comment: Meu código ficou assim, retorna null no browser.. pode me ajudar...

Comment: $txtfile = file_get_contents('rotaclaro.txt');
$regex = 'Cliente:(.*)CPF\/C\.N\.P\.J\.:(.*)\sEndereço:(.*)CEP:(.*)\s{1,}Tel EBT:\s{1,}Tel Res:(.*)Tel Outros:(.*)Tel Comercial:(.*)\sTel Celular:(.*)Tel Fax:(.*)\sReferência(.*)\sSolicitação:(.*)Emissão:(.*)Node:(.*)\s{2,}Agendado para: (.{10}) (.*)OS Número:(.*)\sEQUIPE:(.*)PARCEIRO:(.*)\s{1,}Prepostos:(.*)Portabilidade:(.*)\s{1,}Contrato:(.*)Data de Habilitação:(.*)\s{1,}(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)';
preg_match_all($regex, $txtfile, $dados);
var_dump($dados);

Comment: @Ðracø o seu problema agora está relacionado com encoding acho. Dê uma olhada aqui (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19150/129) e teste `echo mb_detect_encoding($txtfile);`

Comment: Retornou o seguinte: UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar um arquivo XLS e utilizar uma função para obter os valores entre as tabelas, então ao colocar o valor no XLS, automaticamente ele seria adicionado ao MYSQL.

Comment: O intuito de importar o TXT é exatamente criar um XLS do mesmo.

Comment: Mais ele não descreveu Isso.

Comment: Desculpe, alterei meu nome depois do post, eu preciso que as informações sejam exibidas corretamente para que eu possa importar isto para o mysql, e poder gerar um xls depois...